# Does Danse become unavailable as a companion if you join the Institute?

Tags: fallout-4

So I was wondering, does Danse become unavailable as a companion if you join the Institute?

Comment: For point of reference, I just got to Diamond City, story wise. I do not consider this a spoiler in any sense

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this isn't entirely true. You can follow the BOS story missions up to BUT NOT INCLUDING the mission "Tactical Thinking" without hurting your reputation with any other faction. If you follow their story line that far you will complete the mission "Blind Betrayal" which will remove Danse from the Prydwen (if you haven't already moved him) and will remove the threat of him being eliminated with the rest of the brotherhood if you decide to side with the institute. This mission also rewards you with a set of pretty good power armor so I find it's worth it to follow their story line through Blind Betrayal just to get it.

Comment: Just to be clearer, even if you complete blind betrayal then side with the institute you will still lose Danse as a companion

Answer (score 0):

If you *join* the Institute then yes - Danse gets killed when you wipe out the Brotherhood of Steel.

If you're just doing the story leading up to joining the Institute then Danse is still available as a companion but your companions don't teleport with you into the Institute when you visit.

Comment: It wont let me edit because of too few characters and I don't want to change more than is needed, but you should put a spoiler tag over the second part of your first line... Kind of wish I didn't read that...

Comment: If you're worried about spoilers why are you looking at a question that will obviously contain a spoiler in order to be answered correctly? :o

Comment: kalina, definitely not obvious. Maybe I just wanted to know if I shouldn't join the institute if I want to keep Danse? Wrapping that other part in a spoiler tag doesn't make the answer any less correct and I didn't say you should remove it. If it's so obvious that it will contain a spoiler as you say, then it should **definitely** have tags.

Comment: Actually the rule is if it's obvious that it contains a spoiler and a spoiler is required to answer the question *[you shouldn't be looking at it so you can complain about spoilers](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/9809/52800)*. Downvoting people because they won't do what you want is akin to bullying and I don't appreciate it at all.

Comment: I just said it was not obvious... Especially when only considering the question text itself and not reading your answer. The example in the post you linked definitely requires that information in the tag to be answered correctly, I believe your answer would stand fine by itself, with the added detail in the spoiler tag as a bonus benefit to answer **why** he no longer becomes available. Personally, I believe you answer could still be considered complete and make sense with the other information hidden. If my reasoning is not clear, perhaps move this to chat. I doubt this will benefit others.

Comment: Also, I downvoted simply because I feel you answer could be improved with one simple edit. If you disagree, that is fine, but it doesn't make my opinion any less valid, I wasn't doing it to bully, only encourage the improvement. On the other hand, serial downvoting is highly immature, assuming that was you who just downvoted 3 questions of mine, each within 20 seconds of each other. Highly suspicious, wouldn't you say?

Comment: Danse doesn't get killed when you wipe out the BoS if you've completed Blind Betrayal. I've been looking around the internet for a while, and can't find any consensus on what happens to him if you've completed Blind Betrayal, he's still your companion, and you start Airship Down. Seems like it needs testing.